# How to get a list of user-created databases in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Im trying to get a list of all the user-created databases (not tables) from mysql, but I always get a list containing 'mysql', 'information_schema' and 'performance_schema'. Is it possible to filter these 3 out of the whole list?

I have tried with the query 'SHOW DATABASES' using the LIKE and NOT LIKE and also the wildcard '%', but not luck so far. I also tried with logical operators like AND and OR:

```
   SHOW DATABASES NOT LIKE 'information_schema' # doesn´t work
   SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'information_schema' # Works but outputs 1 record.
   SHOW DATABASES WHERE 'Database' NOT LIKE 'information_schema' # Works but doesn´t filter anything.
```

Do you guys have any idea how can I show only the user-created databases in mysql?

**NOTE**

In my view this is not a duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql), because the question is how to get a filtered list of user-created databases and NOT about the use of the backticks.

Best,

Comment: `Database` should be enclosed in backticks, not single quotes i.e. `SHOW DATABASES WHERE \`Database\` NOT LIKE 'information_schema'`

Comment: @Nick My question shouldn´t be marked as duplicate, because Im not asking about the use of the backticks, but about how to get a filtered list of databases.

Comment: If you replace the single quotes in your query (which are wrong, as described in the duplicate) with backticks, your query works fine. So the question is essentially a duplicate, because you already have the answer, it just doesn't work because you have the wrong quotes. Your complete query can be `SHOW DATABASES WHERE \`Database\` NOT IN ('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema')`

Answer (score 1):

Try using backtick for the `Database`
Because this worked for me

```
SHOW DATABASES WHERE `Database` NOT LIKE 'information_schema'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> show databases where `database` not like 'information_schema';
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> show databases where `database` not in('information_schema');
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```